# No file or variants found for asset xcode 14 with flutter 3.7.4

Tags: flutter, xcode

```
No file or variants found for asset: packages/html_editor_enhanced/summernote.html.
```

I try to look all the related topics with my issue but nothing helps to fix this error. can anyone please help I am using xcode 14 with flutter 3.7.4, this is the only error that I am encountering.. thank you for the help.